# How to make error message disappear when Checkbox is Checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, addmodelerror

EDIT:

```
<div class="editor-item">
<label for="Location">Location</label><input class="input-validation-error ui-autocomplete-input" data-jqui-acomp-delay="400" data-jqui-acomp-hiddenvalue="LocationId" data-jqui-acomp-minlength="3" data-jqui-acomp-source="/Loc/Search" data-jqui-type="autocomplete" id="Location" name="Location" type="text" value="123 wrong address" autocomplete="off">
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Location" data-valmsg-replace="true">Location not found</span></div>
```

When the user submit the button I'm checking to see if the location is exists and if not then I'm adding in ModelState.AddmodelError

`ModelState.AddModelError((LocationViewModel m) => m.Location, "Location not found");`

My question is: When the user clicks on Checkbox `Create Location` How can I make the error disappear?

```
 <span id="CreateNLocation"   >
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateLocation, "Create Location")
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CreateLocation)
 </span>
```

Rendered at run time:

```
<span id="CreateNLocation" style="">
   <label for="CreateLocation">Create Location</label>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Create new Location field is required." id="CreateLocation" name="CreateLocation" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

[image]

Comment: Show the model properties and its attributes, and how you generate the html (I assume your using the html helpers). The easiest way to handle this is to use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar validation attribute so that you get both client and server side validation out of the box (no need to add a `ModelState` error

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of the span tag with the error message or looking for a proper validation?

Comment: trying to get rid of the span tag

Comment: I'm using JQueryUIHelper

Comment: do you have duplicate span with data-valmsg-for="Location"

Comment: I don't have dupes `data-valmsg-for="Location"`

Comment: so you can use attribute selector and remove. check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your comments to your question

```
$('#CreateLocation').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("span[data-valmsg-for='Location']").hide();
  } else {
    $("span[data-valmsg-for='Location']").show();
  }
});
```

[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtse2yLz/1/)

Comment: yes it worked! what if the user uncheck the checkbox, how can i bring that back the error message? without posting the entire page again

Comment: instead of removing it from DOM you may want to hide and show

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JS Fiddle example if you want to show/hide it based on if the checkbox has been checked or not.

```
$('#CreateLocation').click(function() {
   var $checkbox = $('#CreateLocation');
   var $errMsg   = $(this).parents('#parent-example')
                        .find('.field-validation-error');
   $checkbox.prop('checked') ? $errMsg.hide() : $errMsg.show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ga7kpn3r/1/

Comment: Placing the code in a wrapper div can ensure you are only removing the specific error element and not all elements that match the data selector or class selector. Just replace my jS fiddle code with the classes/markup you need but the functionality works on toggling the check box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#CreateLocation').click(function() {
    $('.field-validation-error).remove();
});
```

If I am understanding your question properly, you just want to make the error disappear when checking the checkbox? If so this should work for you.

Edit: Misread the question, I need the markup for the error message (div, span, whatever it be). Whatever the element is, replace the .remove() selector with the right one.

```
$('#CreateLocation').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(wrapper).find('.field-validation-error').remove();
});
```

Comment: `<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Location" data-valmsg-replace="true">Location not found</span>`

Comment: I updated the selector to the code. Hopefully this is a working answer for you, there may be a better ASP related solution however (I'm a JS/PHP guy).

Comment: the problem with using class name is that I have more then one with the same class name `field-validation-error` and I do not see that it has `id or name`

Comment: If the checkbox and error message can be placed in inside a wrapper div, you can always use:

$('#CreateLocation').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(wrapper).find('.field-validation-error').remove();
});

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question with what is rendering with `div` tag , please have a look this maybe what you have asked me before